# SQL Updating tables. One contains foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am facing a problem with updating tables. I have two tables:

- `Visit`: visitId, roomId(FK)
- `Room`: roomId, price

How can I update room price for specific `roomId`, but keep old value of price in `Visit`?

For example somebody booked room in hotel for 50$, but after he did it, the price changes to 60$. So I want to keep old price(50$) just for this client and for new ones use the new value (60$).

Thanks for responses

Comment: You must save the price of the room when ordered in the visitit table.

Answer (score 2):

You have a slowly changing dimension.  Probably the best approach is to keep the price in the `visit` table as well.  You can call this the `reservationPrice` or something similar, to distinguish from the current price for the room.

Comment: Thanks for answer. yes, this is a kind of solution but does it make sense to use foreign keys when you save data from other table to another ? Is it proper way to do things like that ?

Comment: @user7215538 . . . This is one way.  Another method is to implement a slowly changing dimension with effective and end dates providing the price.